# How to objectify multiple targets in vbscript?

Tags: testing, object, syntax, vbscript

I am now testing the receiver inside a broadband communication front end chip with vbscript. For example, the following code:

```
Dim target : target = chip
target.receiver1.value = 1    'a simple assignment operation
...
```

I would like to also objectify the receiver1 so that the code looks like the following form:

```
Dim target : target = chip
Dim targetReceiver : targetReceiver = receiver1 
target.targetReceiver.value = 1
...
```

Here I can easily modify the receiver target to, e.g., "`receiver2`" or "`receiverN`" without manually changing the line `target.receiver1.value = 1`. I do understand that the above code will not work, but given what I want to achieve, could you please show me how that can be done?

Comment: Shouldn't *target = chip* be *Set target = chip*?

Comment: You can, with the `execute` statement, but that is not a good programming practice. Consider making collections (by using an `array()` or a [.net arraylist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2007.01.heyscriptingguy.aspx)) so you can access the receiver by `target.targetReceiver(1).value`.